# Aggregate (sum,max,avg) function in Critera API JPA

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

In my criteria API query the following query where I query for three columns of my table works.

**cq.multiselect(root.get("point").get("id"), root.get("player").get("userid"), root.get("amount"));**

but when I want the sum of the column amount using the following query it gives a sql error. The query is

**cq.multiselect(root.get("point").get("id"), root.get("player").get("userid"), cb.sum(root.get("amount"))  );**

The error that I am getting is.

**{"id":"6","result":null,"error":"\r\nInternal Exception: com.sap.dbtech.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc40.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [-8017] (at 8): Column must be group column:ID\r\nError Code: -8017\r\n**

Please help me with this, as I have been stuck on this for hours now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is telling you that you need a group by clause in your query. Every column in the select clause (except the ones which are the result of an aggregate function) must be in the group by clause:

```
criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get("point").get("id"), 
                      root.get("player").get("userid"))
```